# License Number Validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created a JavaScript function for validation of US Driving License. Issue is function is browser dependent. That is function creates error in IE but run fine in MOZILLA AND CHROME..

I have validated it as first three digit should be either 0 or 1 or 2 or 3.

```
    //license number
    var strFilter = /^[0-9]*$/;
    var chkVal36 = document.getElementById("license").value;
    var chkVal37 = document.getElementById("license").value.length;
    var chkVal38 = document.getElementById("license").value;

    if ((!strFilter.test(chkVal36)) || ((chkVal36 !== "") && (chkVal36 === 0)) || (chkVal36 !== "") || (chkVal37 !== 8) || ((chkVal38[0] !== 0) && (chkVal38[0] !== 1) && (chkVal38[0] !== 2) && (chkVal38[0] !== 3))) {
        alert("Please enter valid 8-digit license number\r\n(Only digits)");
        document.getElementById("license").focus();
        document.getElementById("license").style.background = "#DFE32D";
        document.getElementById("license").value = null;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get? You should remove all your extra calls to document.getElementById and replace it with: var license = document.getElementById("license"); I would also change your regex to /^[0-9]+$/ since + will match 1 or more, then you don't need to check for an empty string.

Comment: If I use to enter `12332111`than also it returns false with alert. According to my conditions I have used any one of 0-3 at digit 1

Comment: @row1: Can u please write it in proper way..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do string array indexing like `chkVal38[0]` in older versions of IE.

I would suggest this cleaned up and simplified code:

```
//license number
var strFilter = /^[0-3][0-9]{7}$/;
var obj = document.getElementById("license");

if (!strFilter.test(obj.value)) {
    alert("Please enter valid 8-digit license number\r\n(Only digits)");
    obj.focus();
    obj.style.background = "#DFE32D";
    obj.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZUajd/

Changes:

- Moved all the validation into the single regex (leading 0-3, all numbers and 8 total chars).
- Retrieved the DOM object once and then use that reference rather than retrieving it every time
- Clear the field by setting to "", not null.

Answer (score 1):

Use [0-3] to place that check that the first three digits should be between 0 and 3 ..Check the link to make regex
http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?

Comment: Is their any link that explains JS

Comment: What exactly do you mean by this?? you may want to try out jsfiddle to know how JS works..

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
> var strFilter = /^[0-9]*$/; var chkVal36 =
```

That will match a sequence of zero or more numbers at the start of a string. To check if a string starts with at least 3 digits in the range 0 to 9, use:

```
var strFilter = /^[0-9]{3}/;
```

If you want some other range, put it in the square brackets. The following:

```
> var chkVal36 = document.getElementById("license").value;
> var chkVal37 = document.getElementById("license").value.length; 
> var chkVal38 = document.getElementById("license").value;
```

That should be something like:

```
var licenceNumber = document.getElementById("license").value;
```

The number of characters in the licence can be accessed directly as `licenceNumber.length`. So…

```
if (!strFilter.test(licenceNumber)) {
    // deal with error - doesn't start with 3 digits
}
if (licenceNumber.length != 8) {
    // deal with error - wrong number of characters
}
```